# How do I add Auto-increment value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate **7 digit code**(Alternate ID) for my existing customers.
For example. 
This my existing Customer Table structure

```
ID     Name    Address    City   AlternateID
101    Test1    NO 4,..    LA     0000001  
102    Test2    NO 3,..    TA     0000002
```

We have to run this script on a daily basis.
Last number stored in a different table.
Next day start from the Last number stored in Table.

```
(Ex. 1st day added 30 customers means "0000030" 
     2nd day added 10 customers means "0000040")
```

I want to know the query on how to decrease "0" when digits of the number increased

```
Like - Single-Digit number "0000001"
     - Double-Digit number "0000010"
     - Triple-Digit number "0000100"
```

so on.

Comment: Once you've work out your increasing number, use `FORMAT(yournumber,'0000000')`. What will you do when you reach 9999999? Does the number _really_ need to have no gaps? There is usually no actual reason for this, except that humans find it neater.

Answer (score 3):

You can do :

```
select t.*,
       right(concat('0000000', row_number() over (order by id)), 7) as AlternateID
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
update t
    set alternateid = format(row_number() over (order by id) + ot.max_alternateid, '0000000')
    from t cross join
         othertable ot
    where alternateid is null;
```